# How can I unintern a qualified method?

Tags: methods, lisp, common-lisp, slime, clos

During development I defined an 'initialize-instance :after' method which after a while was not needed anymore and actually gets in my way because inside it calls code that is not valid anymore.  Since the `unintern` function does not have an argument for the qualifier, is there any way I can "unintern" the symbol-qualifier combination of a method so that I don't have to slime-restart-inferior-lisp and load the project again from the start?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the standard functions `find-method` and `remove-method` to do it:

```
(remove-method (find-method #'frob '(:before) '(vehicle t)))
```

I find it's much easier to use the slime inspector. If your function is named `frob`, you can use `M-x slime-inspect #'frob RET` to see a list of all methods on `frob` and select individual methods for removal.

Comment: If you're hoping to use slime-inspect for this sort of thing, ensure you have the "slime-fancy-inspector" in your `slime-contribs`. The generic slime inspector doesn't (at least at present...) make this sort of functionality readily accessible.

Answer (score 5):

See the answer from Xach.

Methods are collected in generic functions. UNINTERN has nothing to do with that. What you want is to remove a method from a generic function.

Most Common Lisp IDEs have a way to do that. Either via the editor (M-x undefine...) or through some inspector tool.

Answer (score 0):

With AllegroCL 9.0. Xach's answer did not completely work for me.

The definition of my method:

```
defmethod my-method* ((expr forall-expr) bindings)
```

forall-expr is a class and bindings is un-typed. To find the method I had to use:

```
(find-method #'my-method* '() (mapcar #'find-class '(forall-expr t)))
```

Then to remove the definition of the method I used:

```
(remove-method #'my-method* (find-method #'my-method* '() (mapcar #'find-class '(forall-expr t))))
```

I was able to figure this out from footnote 7 at http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html and the examples from the Lisp HyperSpec for find-method http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_m.htm.