# Remove one method from a generic function

Tags: common-lisp, clos

I have added the following method to the generic function `speak` but would now like to remove this particular method in the REPL without removing the rest of the generic functions' methods.

```lisp
(defmethod speak :around ((c courtier) string)           ; [1]
  (format t "Does the King believe that ~A?" string)
  (if (eql (read) 'yes)
      (if (next-method-p) (call-next-method))            ; [2]
      (format t "Indeed, it is a preposterous idea.~%"))
  'bow)

[1] The :around method replaces the primary method for the type.
[2] Then it decides whether to call the primary method or not.
```

The [documentation link](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_met.htm) to the function `remove-method` has no examples and I don't know what is the syntax to refer to the actual `:around` method above.

```
(remove-method #'speak)
TOO FEW ARGUMENTS

(remove-method #'speak :around)
NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976470/how-can-i-unintern-a-qualified-method

Comment: yes - might be worth mentioning though that the duplicate uses slightly different terminology, so i don't think I would have known to search for it & why i didn't find it.

Comment: absolutely. Yours is easier to find (so a redirection from here to the answer would have worked).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation:

> remove-method generic-function method

It expects a generic function object and a method object as arguments.

One can find the method via `find-method`.

```
CL-USER 39 > (find-method #'speak
                          (list :around)
                          (list (find-class 'courtier) (find-class t)))
#<STANDARD-METHOD SPEAK (:AROUND) (COURTIER T) 42001285EB>

CL-USER 40 > (remove-method #'speak
                            (find-method #'speak
                                         (list :around)
                                         (list (find-class 'courtier)
                                         (find-class t))))
#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION SPEAK 422000A68C>
```

Note also that a good Lisp development environment may also allow to remove methods in the editor or the inspector.

Note that in the Lisp listener, one does not need to call `find-method` twice like above. The variable `*` contains the last result.

```
CL-USER 43 > (find-method #'speak
                          (list :around)
                          (list (find-class 'courtier)
                                (find-class t)))
#<STANDARD-METHOD SPEAK (:AROUND) (COURTIER T) 4200150DEB>

CL-USER 44 > (remove-method #'speak *)
#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION SPEAK 422000A68C>
```

Here is another interaction example using SLIME in GNU Emacs with the *presentation* feature for SLIME enabled. A *presentation* is Lisp output, which keeps the connection between the printed object and the generated text.

[image: Slime REPL]

Call the `find-method` function. It returns the method. Here we use `presentations`, which keep the connections between text and Lisp objects. The output is displayed in the color red and it is *mouse-sensitive*. Moving the mouse over the red returned object will add interaction options.

Now type `(remove-method #'speak` and then middle-click (or whatever SLIME is configured to use) on the red output: the presentation (the text and the connected object) will be copied to the line. Type `)` and enter the form. SLIME has actually constructed a list with the real object and not the textual representation, then.

This is how repls work on the Symbolics Lisp Machine and in CLIM / McCLIM...

Comment: To clarify why i cannot paste the REPL output from `find-method` as arg to `remove-method` (That gives the error `"objects printed with #<...> cannot be read back in"`), can we be more specific when we say "find the method"?   Can we say "find the internal representation of the method"?  What would be good language to use there? Would it be right to say that's a pointer to the method?

Comment: @mwal: No, we find the method itself. What you try is to copy text, not the method. Actually, there are Lisp systems where you can copy the object in 'repl'.

Comment: @mwal: if you want to reuse an evaluation result in the 'repl' / 'listener', then use variables like `*`, `**`, `***`, which are bound to prior results.

Answer (score 3):

If using GNU Emacs with SLIME, you can also use *slime-inspector*. For example define generic function `foo` and two methods:

```
USER> (defgeneric foo (x))
#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION FOO (0)>

USER> (defmethod foo ((x string)) (length x))
#<STANDARD-METHOD FOO (STRING) {100B4D7E23}>

USER> (defmethod foo ((x integer)) x)
#<STANDARD-METHOD FOO (INTEGER) {100C355843}>
```

You have two main options to enter the inspector:

1. From the REPL, type `#'foo` so that a presentation object for the generic method is printed:

   ```
   USER> #'foo
   #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION FOO (0)>
   ```

   Either *right-click* the presentation (anywhere inside `#<...>`) and select `Inspect`, or put the cursor in the presentation  and press <kbd>C-c C-v TAB</kbd> (`slime-inspect-presentation-at-point`).
2. From a source file, enter `slime-inspect`, a.k.a. <kbd>C-c I</kbd>, and enter `#'foo`.

In both cases, you are shown a view similar to this:

```
#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION {505A9A2B}>
--------------------
Name: FOO
Arguments: (X)
Method class: #<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP:STANDARD-METHOD>
Method combination: #<SB-PCL::STANDARD-METHOD-COMBINATION STANDARD () {1000214003}>
Methods: 
(INTEGER) [remove method]
(STRING) [remove method]

(....)
```

Each `[remove method]` text is actually a button, click or press <kbd>Return</kbd> on any of them to remove the associated method from the generic function.